# Why does this HTML give me "Unexpected token Y"?

Tags: html, meteor, syntax-error

In my Meteor app, I've got this HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>timeandspace</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>A List of the Places I Have Lived</h1>
  {{> addTimeSpaceForm}}
</body>

<template name="addTimeSpaceForm">
    <form>
        <label for="city">City</label>
        <input type="text" name="city" id="city">
        </br>
        <label for="state">State</label>
        <input type="text" name="state" id="state">
        </br>
        <label for="yearin">Year Arrived</label>
        <input type="text" name="yearin" id="yearin">
        </br>
        <label for="yearout">Year Departed</label>
        <input type="text" name="yearout" id="yearout">

        <input type="submit" name="insertdocument" value="Add Time and Space">
    </form>
</template>
```

...but it gives me several errors along this line:

```
"http://localhost:3000/sockjs/info?cb=fxr31xfy93".
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token Y
XHR finished loading: GET
```

Why? What in the world does "Unexpected token Y" indicate, and what in the code above is causing it?

### UPDATE

Reportedly (by MattK) the HTML is fine. I wonder if my problem is that I only checked the "Private networks" checkbox in the Windows Security Alert dialog (unchecked the "Public networks" one? The options I chose (the exact opposite of the default, which made sense to me (obviously) but were perhaps wrongheaded, can be seen [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/HTML/1016053/farwall.png).

If indeed the options I chose are problematic, how can I "go back" and select both checkboxes (or just the public one, if that's the way to go)? I'm doing this at home on a laptop with a "normal" setup - no home network or anything of that nature.

I explored around to see if I could figure it out, but I don't see "Meteor" in the Windows Firewall settings:

[image]

Nor is there an "Evented I/O for V8 JavaScript" in that list.

The Windows Firewall settings show I am not connected to a Private network (I thought maybe that's what my WiFi / ATT&T UVerse connection would be considered, but apparently not), so checking the "allow private" would seemingly be of no value. My suspicions are that this (not having the "public" box checked) may be the problem, but how to rectify that now?

As a side note, I see in Windows Firewall that I'm allowing private and public access to a gazillion "apps and features" named *A..akj;fdfdjkjfdafjkfjddfjafjdfjjdfjfdjdfsaj* and the like.

Is this problematic?

If these are legitimate apps, why are they obscuring their identity by just calling themselves "App.[blaBlaBla]"?

Comment: Those 2 lines are distinct. The second line points to this: https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#user-content-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-y

Your template is fine & that code has nothing to do with the problem. My guess if you've got something wonky going on with your server code.

Comment: The unexpected token is `Y`. The last line is just saying that the async request (the `XHR`) finished loading with the `GET` method.

Comment: @MattK: I have no server code; I wonder if it's because I only "ticked" the "Private networks" checkbox in the Windows Security Alert dialog (unchecked the "Public networks" one? I will add a little more detail in an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my Windows Firewall settings - what I allowed through the Firewall. I had unchecked the recommended-against-but-by-default checked "Public networks" and checked the by-default-unchecked "Private"

It turns out I have no private network, and so that setting was moot.

Not having public checked caused the bizarre error, apparently - once I disabled Windows Firewall, it works fine.

I still would like to know how I can have my Firewall and not let it eat my public network Meteor messages, too, though...